# How to scan directory and save only image file names to array with php?

Tags: php, arrays, glob

I am working on a script that scans a specific directory and saves each image file name to an array. The problem is, I have two txt files in the directory as well. I only want the image file name in the array, I need to exclude the txt files. Because of that, I can't use scandir. Here is what I have so far:

```
$images = glob($post_dir . "{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
$listImages=array();
foreach($images as $image){
    $listImages[]=$image;
}

foreach ($listImages as $singleImg) {
    echo $singleImg;
}
```

I think the problem might actually be in setting the $images variable. In the first foreach, if do `echo $image;` I don't get anything returned.

EDIT: Also, if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish please feel free to share. I am not set on only using glob.

Comment: `$listImages=$image` should be `$listImages[]=$image;` ....that won't help $images being empty, but will actually result in an array in $listImages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with `glob` you can just do:

```
$post_dir = 'giraffe-images/';
$images = glob($post_dir . '*.jpg');
foreach($images as $image){
  echo $image;
}
```

As for your situation, `$listImages` isn't an array after the first `foreach` loop because you're doing:

```
$listImages = $image;
```

I think you mean to do:

```
$listImages[] = $image;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Bill, I am not quite sure what you are suggesting though. With your example, it looks like what I have except I have the directory path saved to $post_dir where you have it written out. Well, you also took out GLOB_BRACE. I did try that but it didn't help.

Comment: No problem! Well, I'm just letting you know the array to build the `$listImages` array isn't needed since `$images` will not just be an array of the images.

Comment: Oh ok I see now, thanks! So, you are definitely correct my problem was nothing more than a simple mistake. I didn't have a forward slash in my directory :/ Your edited answer made me realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say add `echo $post_dir;` to make you you have a slash and you have the right directory.

I wrote this test:

```
<?php
$post_dir = "/tmp/20712147/subdir/";
$images = glob($post_dir . "*.jpg");
$listImages=array();
foreach($images as $image){
    $listImages[]=$image;
}

print_r($listImages);
```

Usage:

```
matt@goliath:/tmp/20712147$ ls
glob.php subdir
matt@goliath:/tmp/20712147$ ls subdir/
readme.txt test1.jpg  test2.jpg
matt@goliath:/tmp/20712147$ php glob.php 
Array
(
    [0] => /tmp/20712147/subdir/test1.jpg
    [1] => /tmp/20712147/subdir/test2.jpg
)
```